# React (Native) setup Jest to test Context component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

The React Context API allows me to place the logic for the app state in one place (and avoid redux). Right now it looks like this

```
// Using the Context API used in react 16.3 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLJN4JfniH4
const { Provider, Consumer: ContextConsumer } = React.createContext()

class ContextProvider extends Component {

  ...// lot of functions ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          getDose: this.getDose,
          getDoseRange: this.getDoseRange,
          setDose: this.setDose,
          checkIN: this.checkIN,
          checkOUT: this.checkOUT,
          getFalsifiedDrug: this.getDefaultproductData,
          updatePrescriptionDose: this.updatePrescriptionDose,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = { ContextConsumer, ContextProvider }
```

Entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/Norfeldt/MedBlockChain/blob/develop/Context.js).

**What's the best practice to build jest tests that allows me to test the functions and don't mess up the state?**

(Would like to **avoid using Enzyme** (developed by AirBnB) - since [AirBnB officially gave up using React Native](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/sunsetting-react-native-1868ba28e30a))

### Example

How do I make a test that confirms that when I call `setDose(2)` that the `productData.dose` was changed from `"5 mg"` and now equals `"2 mg`. But then set the state back to `"5 mg"` for the other test.

### BONUS INFO

I'm having some trouble getting `jest` to work with me (so I can try out the suggested solutions)

> package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "invert-color": "^1.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-28.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.6",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.3.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-codingitwrong": "^0.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^1.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  }
}
```

It just throws this at me

```
> @ test /Users/norfeldt/Desktop/React-Native/MedBlockChain
> jest --watchAll

● Validation Error:

  Module react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js in the haste.hasteImplModulePath option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /Users/norfeldt/Desktop/React-Native/MedBlockChain

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I have tried things like

```
rm -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock package-lock.json && npm install
```

Comment: I think you may use: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme, this library provide a good API to test state and so on.

Comment: Thank you, but AirBnB have stopped using React Native so would like to avoid using it since I expect it to be only aimed for React (web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [react-test-renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) which you're already using in your project specs. 
 What you need is to call [`testRenderer.getInstance()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrenderergetinstance) => check current `state` => invoke some methods you need to test => check updated `state`:

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "react-test-renderer";
import { ContextProvider } from "../Context";

describe("ContextProvider", () => {
  test("it updates dose correctly", () => {
    const component = create(<ContextProvider />);
    const instance = component.getInstance();

    expect(instance.getDose()).toBe(5);
    expect(instance.state.productData.dose).toBe("5 mg");

    instance.setDose(2);

    expect(instance.getDose()).toBe(2);
    expect(instance.state.productData.dose).toBe("2 mg");
  });

  test("it updates something else correctly", () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

State for other tests won't be affected.

The only thing I needed to make this work with your repo is to `npm install whatwg-fetch@2.0.4 --save` as described [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2192#issuecomment-420342527). Hope this helps.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Even though this is supposed to be another question and the obvious solution is to create a new rn project and copy you code in it, but here is what I've done to fix `jest` errors on your code:

**1)** Make versions match (as described in the comments...):

```
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
// and maybe even
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
```

**2)** To fix an error

> api.caller is not a function

use `babel.config.js` as described [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/babel-preset-expo-error-after-upgrading-to-v31/15523):

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    env: {
      development: {
        plugins: ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
      }
    }
  };
};
```

**3)** Use `yarn` due to [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2595#issuecomment-435829288)

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense to me. I just can't get `jest` to work with me so I can try it out. It keeps throwing a `Validation Error` saying `Module react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js in the haste.hasteImplModulePath option was not found.`

Comment: I tried things like `m -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock package-lock.json && npm install`

Comment: That is weird. Haven't faced this problem. The first thing that comes to mind is to [make `expo` and `jest-expo` versions match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814689/react-native-jest-react-native-jest-hasteimpl-js-in-the-haste-hasteimplmodule). Also do not mix npm and yarn. Stick to one thing cuz it may cause some issues. And here's [another suggestion to try](https://forums.expo.io/t/cannot-run-jest/15477)

Comment: I actually been through all the sites you suggested a couple of time before and I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a replacement for Enzyme, I think you should look here: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/

That library will allow you to use the [update](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api#update) function provided to change the values you are testing, then change them back.

Great library for React Native - [the getting started page says it all](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/getting-started). If you are interested in some code to help you get started I can work something up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you only unit-test your logic and consider avoiding component tests altogether in this case.

You can extract your methods into a "Presenter" to process your data and only test this logic. With this approach it's easy to test the presenter which has a pure input/output logic.

The presenter, for example, can look like this:

```
// DosePresenter.js

const processDose = (value, productData) => {
  productData.dose = value.toFixed(0) + productData.dose.replace(/[\d\.]*/g, '')
  productData.productionTime = Conventions.datetimeStr();
  productData.hashSalt = this.makeHashSalt();
  return {productData, productDataHash: getHashOfproductData(productData)};
};

module.exports = {
  processDose
};
```

The usage:

```
// Context.js

import * as DosePresenter from './DosePresenter';

const setDose = (value) => this.setState(DosePresenter.processDose(value, {...this.state}));
```

Now it should be easier to test the logic:

```
// DosePresenter.test.js

describe('DosePresenter tests', () => {
  let uut;

  beforeEach(() => {
    uut = require('./DosePresenter');
  });

  it('should process a dose', () => {
    const value = 10;
    const productData = {};
    expect(uut.processDose(value, productData)).toEqual(...);
  });
};
```